# Блокировка потоков Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized, deadlock

Задание: Выполнить приложение командной строки с двумя параметрами, один из которых – количество потоков, другой параметр – количество выводимых строк.
Нужно так синхронизовать потоки, чтобы имена потоков выводились поочередно- в каждой строке. Под синхронизацией подразумевается использование конструкции synchronized и методов wait, notify.
Не использовать в этом задании флаги для синхронизации потоков, а только методы wait и notify. Также не использовать любые задержки для потоков после начала их работы в виде методов sleep, yield или wait c параметром.
Имя первого потока должно всегда выводится в новой строке.

Пример вывода для приложения с параметрами 3 и 2:

Thread-0 Thread-1 Thread-2

Thread-0 Thread-1 Thread-2

Мой код:

```
class Task implements Runnable {
private Task prevTask;
private int number;
static private int numberOfLines;
static private int numberOfTasks;
static private boolean isBegin;

Task(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

void setPrevTask(Task prevTask) {
    this.prevTask = prevTask;
}

static void setStaticFields(int numberOfLines, int numberOfTasks) {
    Task.numberOfLines = numberOfLines;
    Task.numberOfTasks = numberOfTasks;
    Task.isBegin = true;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        if (isBegin && number == 0) {
            isBegin = false;
        } else {
            synchronized (prevTask) {
                try {
                    prevTask.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    System.err.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " was interrupted");
                }
            }
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ");
            if (number == numberOfTasks - 1) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            this.notify();
        }

    }
}


public class Lab4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal number of arguments");
        }
        int numberOfTasks = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        Task.setStaticFields(numberOfLines, numberOfTasks);
        Task[] tasks = new Task[numberOfTasks];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++) {
            tasks[i] = new Task(i);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfTasks + 1; i++) {
            int index = (i + numberOfTasks) % numberOfTasks;
            tasks[index].setPrevTask(tasks[(numberOfTasks + i - 1) % numberOfTasks]);
            new Thread(tasks[index], "Thread-" + index).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Здесь происходит блокировка потоков. Я правильно понимаю, что когда-то notify вызывается раньше, чем соответствующий wait или проблема в другом? Как можно это не допустить или исправить?

Comment: Вы вообще понимаете смысл строки `synchronized (this)` в методе `run()` потока? Если да, опишите в 2 словах, т.к. это самая распространенная ошибка которую я видел в программировании потоков.

Comment: Я думаю, это означает, что поток может зайти в этот блок кода, только если объект, для которого применялось synchronized, свободен

Comment: Метод `run` в данном примере выполняется ТОЛЬКО из текущего потока, никто другой его не вызывает. Поэтому синхронизировать его по объекту `this` нет смысла

Comment: Но я здесь еще использую synchronized (prevTask) это предыдущий объект в очереди, т.е. когда в другом потоке в методе run исполнение дойдет до synchronized (this) выполнение не начнется, пока не будет отпущен мьютекс на него, который был захвачен в synchronized (prevTask), или я что-то неверно понимаю?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы пытаетесь решить задачу процедурным путем. Не могли бы вы объяснить ДРУГИМИ словами задачу ,т.к. некоторые вещи я не понял. Например, что такое второй параметр - число строк? У вас 2 одинаковые строки в примере. Я так понял, нужно стартовать 3 потока и с помощью описанных выше механизмов синхронизации попытаться их вывести по возрастанию их "номеров". Правильно?

Comment: Почти так, только после того, как мы вывели название последнего потока, то должны вернуться к первому и продолжать их выводить до тех пор, пока не выведем нужное количество строк - второй параметр, т.е. если у нас параметры 3 и 100, то мы должны синхронизировать их так, чтобы было выведено Thread-0 Thread-1 Thread-2 100 раз

Comment: С учетом того, что из состояния wait поток может выходить по спецификации произвольно, задача очень интересная

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется чтобы совсем голову не сломать здесь надо применить очередь сообщений. Вспомним Алана Кея и его знаменитые фразы:

> Я считал объекты чем-то вроде биологических клеток, и/или отдельных
>   компьютеров в сети, которые могут общаться только через сообщения.
>
> Большая идея это «сообщения»

```
public class WThread2 extends Thread {

    private static int numberOfLines;
    private static int numberOfThreads;

    private static final Queue<Message> messageQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    public static synchronized void addMessage(Message msg){
        messageQueue.add(msg);
    }
    private static synchronized Message getMessage(){
        return messageQueue.peek();
    }

    private static synchronized Message remove(){
        return messageQueue.poll();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Читаем входные параметры
        if (args.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal number of arguments");
        }
        numberOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        //Создаем и запускаем потоки
        Worker[] workers;
        workers = new Worker[numberOfThreads];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
            workers[i] = new Worker();
            workers[i].start();
        }

        //Создаем очередь сообщений
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < numberOfThreads; j++) {
                addMessage(new Message(Thread.currentThread(), workers[j], workers[j].getName()));
            }
            addMessage(new Message(Thread.currentThread(), workers[0], "\n"));
        }

        synchronized (Worker.class) {
            Worker.class.notifyAll();
        }

        while (!messageQueue.isEmpty()){
            synchronized (Worker.class) {
                try {
                    Worker.class.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Worker extends Thread{

        public Worker(){
            setDaemon(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            synchronized (Worker.class) {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        Worker.class.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Message msg = getMessage();
                    if (msg!=null && msg.from.getName().equals("main") && msg.to == this) {
                        remove();
                        System.out.print(msg.txt());
                    }
                    Worker.class.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Message{
        public final Thread from;
        public final Thread to;
        private final String txt;
        public Message(final Thread from, final Thread to, final String txt){
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.txt = txt;
        }
        public String txt(){
            return txt + " ";
        }
    }
}
```